# Why windows 7 requires TPM or USB for bitlocker?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb

Why not save the private key unenscrypted on the original hard disk and require password every reboot?

That seems to be the way things work in this question
[Is USB based bitlocker as safe as tpm based?](https://superuser.com/questions/810270/is-usb-based-bitlocker-as-safe-as-tpm-based)

My concern is that the USB may be damaged.

What's the use of the USB anyway, and what can a USB do that a regular partition in hard disk cannot?

Comment: You can take a USB stick with you when you are away from your computer ...

Answer (score 1):

This is because the Drive with the operating system on is encrypted - so the key cannot be read from there, bitlocker creates a separate system partition with the needed files to boot and check the bitlocker information provided to decrypt the operating system disk and continue boot.

if you are worried about the usb stick with the key on being damaged, you can also create a bitlocker recovery usb stick which will allow you to get back into operation.  this can of course then be kept somewhere much safer then the usb with the key on.

see this step by step guide from Microsoft, it may answer a few questions for you

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c61f2a12-8ae6-4957-b031-97b4d762cf31

Comment: Yes. But why can't microsoft create an unenscrypted partition and store the key there. After all, correct password must be inserted before the content can be descrypted right?

Comment: What can a USB do that a small unenscrypted partition can't?